# New files aren't showing up only folders

Tags: windows, git

I'm relatively new to git. I'm using:

```
git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1
```

Powershell & Poshgit

I've added one new folder and one new file to my repository. When i do a git status i see the folder but not the file. Why?

[image]

In the untracked folder you see there is 1 .sql file and yes i'm sure its not in .gitignore (i've changed .sql files recently and they were tracked).

If i do a `git add .` will the file that is not shown be added?

Update:
I just had to add the directory and the file automatically shows up. I'm assuming if i had multiple files all of them whould show up. See the command i executed below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git status` is reporting that you have an entire directory without any files that you have `git add`ed. As soon as you `git add` one of the files inside the directory, it will list them.

Comment: Well i didn't add the file but the directory which caused the file to show up.

Comment: @user127954 When you 'added the directory', what you really did was added all the _files_ in the directory. Git doesn't keep track of directories, only files.

Answer (score 1):

That's a simplification of git. It knows that it doesn't track any file in that folder, so it just shows the folder name instead of all files it contains.